# Manipulating dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, data, dataset

I have a dataset in form of {{typ1,typ2,typ3..typ15},.....{typ1,typ2,typ3,...typ15}}. The attached image shows the table form of data. I want to select any 3 column of the data and do some calculation on selected columns, for example (type1, type2,type3) or (type8, type12,type15). What I need, is to give the user ability to select the desired 3 columns and then do the calculation some how to manipulate the selection at begging.
Thank you for your help.
[image]

Comment: The question you have posed is unclear. **(1)** `Manipulate` has a special meaning in Mathematica. **(2)** `Dataset` is a reserved word and is different from `List`. **(3)** " What I need, is to give the user ability to select ..." : It is not clear whether you want a GUI or want to use simple commands such as `Part`. **(4)** What do you mean by `"manipulate the selection at begging"` ? You can include the data you have shown as a picture using copy-paste directly from the input cell and then rephrase and edit your question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: A more idiomatic use of `Dataset` (with ***rows*** of data, i.e. the `Transpose` of your data): `ds = AssociationThread["Type" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range@15,  RandomReal[1, {15, 30}]] // Dataset;` -- Select three rows and apply a function to them individually: `ds[{"Type8", "Type12", "Type15"}, Mean]` -- Multiply three rows:
Normal@ds[#Type8 * #Type12 * #Type15 &]`

Answer (score 3):

First we need some data set:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {10, 5}];
header = Table["Type" <> ToString[i], {i, 5}];
ds = (<|Thread[header -> #]|>) & /@ data  // Dataset
```

[image]

Then assume the user made some selection of columns:

```
selection = {2, 3};
t1 = ds[[All, selection]]
```

[image]

To add the second column to the third one:

```
t2 = t1[Values]
t2[All, Total]
```

[image]

To multiply column 2 and 3:

```
t2[All, Times @@ # &]
```

[image]